# Batch file with Loops doesn't work

Tags: windows, batch

I made the following batch file to sort some files, but I don't know why it does not work:

```
    pause
    for /l %%x in (1, 1, 12) do (
    FOR /L %%G IN (1,1,24) DO (
    for /r %%a in (*%%x*%%G*) do copy "%%a" C:\anyPath\anyText%%xanyText%%G.anyfile

    )
    )
    pause
```

What it should do is ,
 
search for *1*1* if found, rename it to  anyText1anyText1.anyfile
 
search for *1*2* if found, rename it to  anyText1anyText2.anyfile
 
search for *1*3* if found, rename it to  anyText1anyText3.anyfile
 
...

Comment: So what does it do? What output does it give you?

Comment: Your batch file works here with the appropriate test files ...

Comment: it says pause and when i press enter it closes